# how to get errors(if possible), exceptions,fails,success counts and ids from jdbctemplate batchupdate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using the below code to do the same. Whenever an sql error occurs(eg: number out of range) batch update stops and getting the result(int array) as null. so i added `ignore` to the `update` statement.

Now the batch is getting completed ignoring the sqlerror. This time I am getting failureids(ids skipped) and successids(ids processed as well as errors and exceptions). But i want the counts/ids of success,failures,errors,exceptions separately. how do I do that?

Also i added `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` which helped gain so much time in inserting but updating still has performance issues. Updating 3000 records seems to take around 10 - 20 seconds. How do I overcome this?

Technologies used : **spring, springjdbctemplate,mysql,intellij idea,java**.

```
List<String> successList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> failureList = new ArrayList<>();


    int result[] = null;
    int count = 0;
    int successCount = 0;
    int failCount = 0;
    int notAavailable = 0;
    int resultSetIndx = 0;
    try {

                result = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                        "update ignore xxx set yy = ?, zz = ? where aa = ?",
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps,int i) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("aa").toString()));
                        ps.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("bb").toString()));
                        ps.setString(3, new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("cc").toString());
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return jsonArray.length();
                    }
                } );
        for(int affectedRow : result){
            if(affectedRow == 0){
                failureList.add(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(failCount+successCount).toString()).get("u_item_code").toString());
                failCount++;
            }else{
                successList.add(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(failCount+successCount).toString()).get("u_item_code").toString());
                successCount++;
            }
            resultSetIndx++;
        }
        System.out.println("failCount = "+failCount);
        System.out.println("successcount = "+successCount);
        System.out.println(failureList);
        System.out.println(successList);


    }

    catch (DataAccessException e){

        Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();

        System.out.println("Batch update failed: "+e);

        if(rootCause instanceof BatchUpdateException){
            try{
                System.out.println("inside instance of batchupdateexception");
                BatchUpdateException bue = (BatchUpdateException)rootCause;
                int lastSuccessfullRow = bue.getUpdateCounts().length;
                int failurePoint = lastSuccessfullRow+1;
                int continuePoint = lastSuccessfullRow+2;

                successCount+=lastSuccessfullRow;
                failCount++;

                System.out.println("Last successful row: "+lastSuccessfullRow);
                System.out.println("Failed row: "+failurePoint);
                System.out.println("continue point: "+continuePoint);
            }catch(Exception exp){
                System.out.println("Error occured at batch update"+exp.getMessage());
                throw new Exception(exp);
            }
        }else{
            //if rootcause is not BatchUpdateException, then re-throw the exception
           throw new Exception(e);
        }

    }catch(Exception exp){
        System.out.println("Exception occured"+exp);
        throw new Exception(exp);
    }
```

Comment: despite what you've done here, I suggest you to use spring batch which will gives you much more performance. It gives you multi threading mechanisms and is specially developed for huge data processing.

Comment: @HaMi tried spring-batch. Now facing some issues. if you like to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219092/how-to-import-from-xls-to-mysql-database-using-springbatch