# how to overwrite using spring jdbctemplate batchupdate while inserting records?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

Need to insert records using spring jdbctemplate batch update.  while inserting if duplicate record is found, the record needs to be updated else inserted. how do i do that?
Below is my code.

Note:have not included exception handling.

```
 result = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "insert ignore xxx set yy = ?, zz = ? where aa = ?",
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("aa").toString()));
                    ps.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("bb").toString()));
                    ps.setString(3, new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString()).get("cc").toString());
                }

                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return jsonArray.length();
                }
            } );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the following choices:

1. as @fbokovikov said you can use `merge` sql command.
2. you can check if the record is exist or not. In case of performance you can first get all the keys from db and then generate correct insert and update queries using those keys. In this scenario you should be aware of poor performance if you have big data in your table.
3. you can delete records first and then insert them all. This is very bad in performance. :-)

Hope that helps

Comment: The only reason for me to go for batchupadte is performance. Since the 2 and 3 will affect performance, let me try 1. i have another question regarding batchupdate, if you like to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187244/how-to-get-errorsif-possible-exceptions-fails-success-counts-and-ids-from-jdb

Comment: if performance is so  important to you try to use multi threading and connection pools and have a look at spring batch framework.

Comment: tried spring-batch. Facing some issues. if you like to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219092/how-to-import-from-xls-to-mysql-database-using-springbatch.

Answer (score 0):

> Need to insert records using spring jdbctemplate batch update. while
>   inserting if duplicate record is found, the record needs to be updated
>   else inserted

For this purpose you should use standard SQL-2003 command [merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)).

In MySQL this command has following syntax:

[INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: thanks. Now the requirement changed. I will give merge and  INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a try whenever possible.